# Pytorch's nn.TransformerEncoder "src_key_padding_mask" not functioning as expected

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, transformer-model

Im working with Pytorch's `nn.TransformerEncoder` module. I got input samples with (as normal) the shape (`batch-size, seq-len, emb-dim`). All samples in one batch have been zero-padded to the size of the biggest sample in this batch. Therefore I want the attention of the all zero values to be ignored.

The documentation says, to add an argument `src_key_padding_mask` to the `forward` function of the `nn.TransformerEncoder` module. This mask should be a tensor with shape (`batch-size, seq-len`) and have for each index either `True` for the pad-zeros or `False` for anything else.

I achieved that by doing:

```py
. . .

def forward(self, x):
    # x.size -> i.e.: (200, 28, 200)

    mask = (x == 0).cuda().reshape(x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
    # mask.size -> i.e.: (200, 20)

    x = self.embed(x.type(torch.LongTensor).to(device=device))
    x = self.pe(x)

    x = self.transformer_encoder(x, src_key_padding_mask=mask)

    . . .
```

Everything works good when I dont set the `src_key_padding_mask`. But the error I get when I do is the following:

```
File "/home/me/.conda/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 4282, in multi_head_attention_forward
    assert key_padding_mask.size(0) == bsz
AssertionError
```

Seems seems like it is comparing the first dimension of the mask, which is the batch-size, with `bsz` which probably stands for batch-size. But why is it failing then? Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue, which is not a bug: [pytorch's Transformer implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Transformer.html#torch.nn.Transformer) requires the input `x` to be `(seq-len x batch-size x emb-dim)` while yours seems to be `(batch-size x seq-len x emb-dim)`.

Comment: I believe this dimensionality order depends on whether he specifies `batch_first=True` argument on the `nn.Transformer` constructor or not